# When/how does Public Beta end?

Tags: discussion

After what time frame and/or under what conditions will the site leave public beta and become a full-fledged SE site?  I saw a similar meta question discussing the upgrade from private beta to public beta, but see no such discussion of leaving public beta.  How does this occur?

Also, assuming there are conditions that must be met in order to leave public beta, how are we doing in regard to them so far?  If we're falling behind on any of them, what can we do to bolster our success?

Comment: [**Here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139369/what-is-the-average-length-of-time-new-sites-are-in-public-beta), from last summer, on average length. Key benchmarks, and our progress toward them, are on the Area51 proposal site, [**here**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners). You can also see how we stack up against other Beta sites [**here**](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#answers); note that the list is sortable. (Can you tell I've been wondering?!)

Comment: @StoneyB So basically from those stats, we rock at everything except getting people here and making them post questions!!  We're not quite at the rep limits yet either, but since the site is so new that doesn't bother me. Thanks for all the information!! Seems like we're doing pretty good, just have to keep it up. I was surprised to hear how long the betas can last though--I'd be pretty upset if the beta lasted 300 days and then the site went away!!

Comment: Building the audience is the main thing; and it's very early days yet. QQ/day is going to drop as we emerge from the honeymoon, but if we get the visits, it'll go back up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This blog post covers the basic process of evaluating a site for graduation:

[**When will my site graduate?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Here's another blog post that offers another take on the statistics involved — or more precisely, how you shouldn't obsess over the statistics at all:

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

You guys are doing fine, but it is way way ***way*** too early to start obsessing over numbers. From here on out, that's not your job. The task at hand is to compile a great collection of knowledge. That's about it. That means asking intriguing questions when you have them, really knocking out (and constantly improving) some great answers where you can, and to [vote early and often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)… to encourage better answers and to recognize and motivate those who contribute their hard-earned knowledge and experience here. There's some [meta governance](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) that goes with keeping the site moving in the right direction, but that's about all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks Robert!  I really appreciate your response, and the "When will my site graduate" blog post answered a lot of my questions.  This is my first time participating in a beta, so I wasn't aware of those things, but it makes a lot of sense.  We've got a long way to go and just need to keep working to make the site a great place! :)  Thanks for your time and response!